# Editing an entity's decorated text

Tags: draftjs

We have a `Figure` decorator which allows us to insert a link which you can hover over to get a preview of an image. We insert this image along with some metadata (caption, etc.) using a modal form. This all works great. However we also want the ability to click the link and pop up the modal to edit it.

`Entity.replaceData()` works great for updating the metadata, the only problem that remains is the decorated text which comes from the modal too. It appears the Entity knows little to nothing about the content it's decorating.

How can we find and replace the text? Is there a way around this?

(I've tried setting the content in Draft to an arbitrary single character and making the decorator show the content/title (which would be fine), however when trying to delete the figure, Draft seems to jump over the content and delete something before it. I guess it's due to different text lengths. I thought setting it as 'IMMUTABLE' would solve this but that didn't help.)

**EDIT:**

Here's my decorator:

```js
function LinkedImageDecorator(props: Props) {
  Entity.mergeData(props.entityKey, { caption: "hello world" });

  const entity = Entity.get(props.entityKey);
  const data = entity.getData();
  return <LinkedImage data={data} text={props.children} offsetKey={props.offsetKey} />
}

function findLinkedImageEntities(contentBlock: ContentBlock, callback: EntityRangeCallback) {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges((character) => {
    const entityKey = character.getEntity();
    return (
      entityKey != null &&
      Entity.get(entityKey).getType() === ENTITY_TYPE.IMAGE
    );
  }, callback);
}

export default {
  strategy: findLinkedImageEntities,
  component: LinkedImageDecorator,
  editable: false,
};
```

As you can see, I'm testing out `Entity.mergeData` which will eventually be the callback of my `LinkedImage` component (which would open a modal onClick.) So the metadata is easy to update, I just need to be able to update the decorated text which is passed in as `props.children`.

Comment: a click prompt user to set new link text or link href?

Comment: @JiangYD that's what I'm doing with the modal. But from the Decorator, how could I update the content in Draft?

Comment: I not understand what you need to do. what is `content` you mean? everything in editor's state is the content. maybe some code or picture make the question more clear.

Comment: I not know how you set the text, so can not help more. But `https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier.html#replacetext` should work

Comment: @JiangYD Yep that's my problem. I don't have access to `contentState` in the decorator 

Comment: Strategy gets `contentState` as an argument. See https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/tweet/tweet.html#L87 for example

Comment: @Mikhail how can I pass that into my `LinkedImageDecorator` though? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally solved this with the help of [Jiang YD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555300/jiang-yd) and [tobiasandersen](https://github.com/tobiasandersen). Here goes...

First I inject my decorator with a reference to my editor (which keeps track of `EditorState`):

```js
const decorators = new CompositeDecorator([{
  strategy: findLinkedImageEntities,
  component: LinkedImageDecorator,
  props: { editor: this }
}];

this.editorState = EditorState.set(this.editorState, { decorator });
```

From there I can do this in my `LinkedImageDecorator`:

```js
const { decoratedText, children, offsetKey, entityKey, editor } = this.props;

// This looks messy but seems to work fine
const { startOffset, blockKey } = children['0'].props;

const selectionState = SelectionState.createEmpty(blockKey).merge({
  anchorOffset: startOffset,
  focusOffset: startOffset + decoratedText.length,
});

const editorState = editor.getEditorState();

let newState = Modifier.replaceText(
  editorState.getCurrentContent(),
  selectionState,
  "my new text",
  null,
  entityKey,
);

editor.editorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newState, 'insert-fragment');
```

Not sure if this is the cleanest way of doing this but it seems to work well!

Answer (score 3):

just put the global component instance reference in the decorator props.

```
const compositeDecorator = new CompositeDecorator([
{
    strategy: handleStrategy,
    component: HandleSpan,
    props: {parent:refToYourComponentWhichContainsTheEditorState}
}

props.parent.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()
```